# able to trap numbers and symbols of a user input string

Tags: java

Here's the code

do{

```
   System.out.print("Enter your first name:");

   firstname= scan.nextLine();

   Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\s]+");

  Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(firstname);

  if (matcher.matches()) {

  }else{

      System.out.println("Firstname must not contains numbers or symbols");}

if (firstname.length()<3) {

    System.out.println("Error! Firstname must consist 3 or more characters.");

}else if(firstname.length()>20){

     System.out.println("Error! Firstname must not exceed in 20 characters.");   


}else{

    System.out.println("Data Ok");

break;

}

  } while(true);
```

Here are 3 sample output of this code:

1.
Enter your first name:johan34

Firstname must not contains numbers or symbols

Data Ok

2.
Enter your first name:10

Firstname must not contains numbers or symbols

Error! Firstname must consist 3 or more characters.

Enter your first name:

3.
Enter your first name:johan

Data Ok

As you can see, it won't trap numbers and symbols. I would really appreciate any of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z\\s]+");
do{
   System.out.print("Enter your first name:");
   firstname= scan.nextLine();
   Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(firstname);
  if (matcher.matches() && firstname.length() >= 3 && firstname.length() <= 20 ) {
        System.out.println("Data Okay");
        break;
  } else if (!matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Firstname must not contains numbers or symbols");
  } else if (firstname.length()<3){
        System.out.println("Error! Firstname must consist 3 or more characters.");
  } else {
        System.out.println("Error! Firstname must not exceed in 20 characters.");  
  }
  } while(true);
```

Comment: Might be best to also explain some of *why* in your answer so OP can get a better understanding